# Coldfusion 10 CFchart tag is merging bars

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

I am trying to use cfchart tags for bar charts but when I take the exact code from a site:

```
<cfscript>
   border={"color":"blue","radius":6,"width":2};
</cfscript>
 <cfchart format="html" type="bar" showlegend="false" chartHeight="400" chartWidth="600"   border="#border#">
   <cfchartseries >
         <cfchartdata item="2015" value=20>
         <cfchartdata item="2016" value=40>
         <cfchartdata item="2017" value=60>
   </cfchartseries>
 </cfchart>
```

It shows the following:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

Any one experience this? See how it combines everything into one large orange figure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: The documentation on `<cfchartseries>`, https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfchartseries.html, states that the type attribute is required.  Your code does not have one.  It would have been a lot easier if this had resulted in an error.

Comment: That was it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That ws exactly what I needed!!! Here is what I put in: `<cfchartseries type="bar">` and it separated the bars. Now I can read up and further customize! Thank you so much!  [image]